# Misunderstanding a passage in derivation continuity equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current, symmetry, classical-electrodynamics

Electric current density: $${\bf{j}} = \sum_i q_i \delta\bigl({\bf x} - {\bf x}_i(t)\bigr) \frac{dx_i^k}{dt} \tag{1}$$

with $q_i$ charge of the i-th particle, $k$ denotes spacial components of the $4$-vector $x^\mu$, it runs from $1$ to $3$.

We calculate its divergence

$$\nabla \cdot{\bf{j}} = \sum_{k=1}^3\sum_i q_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\delta\bigl({\bf x} - {\bf x}_i(t)\bigr) \frac{dx_i^k}{dt} \tag{2}$$

Using this property: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x-y) = - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x-y)$$

we obtain

$$\nabla \cdot{\bf{j}} = - \sum_{k=1}^3\sum_i q_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i^k}\delta\bigl({\bf x} - {\bf x}_i(t)\bigr) \frac{dx_i^k}{dt} \tag{3}$$

And now that's what I don't get, in the next passage we write

$$\nabla \cdot{\bf{j}} = - \sum_i q_i \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\delta\bigl({\bf x} - {\bf x}_i(t)\bigr)  \tag{4}$$

as if we simplified $\partial x_i^k$ with $dx_i^k$ and then applied $\frac{d}{dt}$ to the $\delta$.

What actually happens between $(3)$ and $(4)$. The simplification i assumed is not formal but may it be right? Is there a way to go from $(3)$ to $(4)$ in a more formal way?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Confusing notation: 1) What is $k$ in the first equation? 2) In the first equation, the $\delta$ term does not depend on $i$, so it can be put in front of the sum? 3) The difference between (2) and (3) looks very strange with a single new occurrence of index $i$. Anyway, calculating directly the derivative of a distribution is hazardous, better to involve test functions (see theory of distributions).

Comment: @claudechuber  
I edited the question hoping it's clearer now, thank you for pointing those things out, especially the point (2): I totally forgot the i.

Comment: Hint: look at it the other way round, going from (4) to (3) looks like the simple application of the chain rule. This needs however to be justified in the sense of distributions (apply it to a test function and check that it works).

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you it looks pretty clear right now actually. Thanks. I'll check tomorrow the validity in the sense of distribution.

Comment: Glad it helped, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: look at it the other way round, going from (4) to (3) looks like the simple application of the chain rule. This needs however to be justified in the sense of distributions (apply it to a test function and check that it works).

BTW, the chain rule allows you to jump directly from (4) to (2), step (3) is unnecessary (and confusing). Indeed, for a regular function $\omega$ defined on the space and a point ${\bf s}(t)$ moving in that space, you would simply write 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigl(\omega({\bf x}-{\bf s}(t))\bigr)=-D\omega({\bf x}-{\bf s}(t)){\dot {\bf s}}(t)\\
=-\sum_k\frac{d\omega}{dx^k}({\bf x}-{\bf s}(t)) {\dot s^k}(t).$$